What is a simple model of telescope sensitivity?
I am looking for a simple model of how sensitive a telescope is to low numbers of incoming photons. A train of individual photons hit one pixel of a detector, and I want to know what the numeric output of the pixel would be.
One model could be: the detector has a spectral response that gives the probability an photon of a given wavelength would be detected. The detector either counts or does not count each individual photon according to this probability, and sends to the computer the final count over some time period.
From this page about the LSST, there is a spectral response diagram (below). I'm wondering, can the colored lines in this diagram be interpreted as a probability each photon would be detected? So for example, the teal line for the g detector reaches 0.4 at 500 nm, so does that mean that a single 500 nm photon would have a 40% chance of triggering the g detector?

Or should the single-photon detection rate be lower than 40%? 40% seems pretty high to me, but maybe it's just that good.
Or is there some thresholding involved, so that the detector is unable to count photons if the arrival rate is too low?
This is just a hobbyist project. What I want is a simple model that I can plug publicly available numbers into, to get a reasonable approximation of how well a given telescope could detect a very dim object emitting light of a given frequency. (I also know about the point spread function, but this question is about the detector.)

did you follow the link to: https://smtn-002.lsst.io ? Note that these are highly technical design documents, and unless an expert with knowledge of the project chimes in: you can read just as well as the rest of us.

@JEB Yes, I did follow that link. They give a SNR formula there with some terms undefined, and for the full explanation they link to a document "LSE-40" which is no longer available. Anyway SNR formula should be more complex than just the model of how it counts photons, shouldn't it? Although I might be able to reconstruct the latter if I had the former.

@JEB Oh, I didn't read beyond that because I got stuck trying to find LSE-40 . They have a Source Counts formula which looks like what I need!

Telescopes are not used for single photons. Pixels usually collect many during the exposure time.

There is a company called Sharpcap that astronomers use. There is a presentation on how and how many photons are collected and why.

All you are really interested in is the signal to noise ratio of your detector. That can be easily established with a series of dark field exposures. It will go pixel by pixel because most pixel detectors have "hot" pixels that are particularly noisy. You don't need to model anything. Your instrument tells you exactly how sensitive it is.

@PhysicsDave photomultiplier tubes detect single photons, so maybe a fly's eye cosmic ray telescope (Cherenkov showers), or "neutrino telescope", but optical focusing stuff: no way.

This question seems to be about photodetectors, not telescopes.
If $N$ photons fall on the active area of a pixel then $\epsilon_Q N$ photoelectrons will be produced. where $\epsilon_Q$ is the quantum efficiency of the detector. a 40% quantum efficiency sounds middle-of-the-range to me. Maybe a little on the good side.
The photons per second $R_N$ is then converted into a current electrons per second $I = e R_e = e\epsilon_Q R_N$. Depending on the sensor type this current will be passed through a transimpedance amplifier with gain $R_T$ (dimensions of resistivity) resulting in a photovoltage $V=I R_T$ which is then converted, using an analog-to-digital converter, into a binary number a certain number of bits long representing the photo-intensity. Alternatively, the current might be collected in an electron "bucket" from some exposure time $T$ and then the total stored charge $Q=IT$ is put onto a capacitor $C$ and read out as a voltage $V=Q/C$ which is converted to a digital number.
It's not clear what exactly is shown in the graph you show (I haven't thoroughly read the link). There are absorptive, reflective, diffractive, losses between the input pupil of the telescope and photodetection. The telescope has finite NA etc. All of these contribute to a finite "throughput" of photons through the system. In fact, looking at the caption for a second, it looks like atmospheric absorption is even included in that throughput. So no, that is not a graph of the quantum efficiency. The quantum efficiency would be higher than the lines shown.
Note that quantum efficiency IS wavelength dependent. This is what leads to the varying of the responsivity with wavelength.

So there must be some error between the $e_QN$ photoelectrons and the actual digital count, right? How is that error quantified? I'm specifically wondering about a fast moving, dim object that could cross multiple pixels while leaving only a few photons in each pixel, so we can't just look at SNR in a single pixel, we need to aggregate many measurements that would be insufficient individually.

@causative What kind of sensor is it? CCD probably? Better yet, what is the make and model # of the sensor? In a CCD the dominant noise sources are photon shot noise which will scales like $\sqrt{N_e} = \sqrt{\epsilon_Q N}$ and dark counts which arise from thermally generated electrons in the semiconductor pixel which are captured similarly to photo-generated electrons. There is also some read noise that comes in when converting the trapped charge into a voltage and digital value. There's also quantization noise which comes from quantizing the photocounts into so many bits.

You can consider an EMCCD sensor which is designed to capture low #s of photons per pixel per exposure. They also make PMT (photomultiplier tube) arrays. For low photon counts you're looking for a sensor with very low dark count(rate)s and low read noise. You may have to sacrifice bandwidth, dynamic range, and cost.

The LSST CCD sensors are deep depleted high-resistivity silicon back-illuminated photodiodes with about 90% quantum efficiency over most of the visual and near IR wavelengths. Efficiency falls off rapidly above about 900 nm and below 450 nm. The following link has more details on the sensor https://www.rebeccaanncoles.com/data/aas227_poster.pdf
